# Case in mysql to execute another query based on condition

Tags: mysql

I have a problem, the concept is value from `@count` to perform if and execute the query. What should I do to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_dana_user WHERE userid=1234 AND password=1234) = 0)
            THEN (SELECT * FROM tb_dana_user) 
            ELSE (SELECT 'bar') 
    END
```

When I change `SELECT * FROM tb_dana_user` to `SELECT 'its true'`, it's working properly. How to fix this case? Sorry for bad english  .the concept is when its true then the query will execute `SELECT * FROM tb_dana_user`

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` expression evaluates to a value, i.e. it is used to evaluate to one of a set of results, based on some condition.
Example:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN type = 1 THEN 'foo'
    WHEN type = 2 THEN 'bar'
    ELSE 'foo-bar'
END AS column_name
FROM sometable`
```

The CASE statement executes one of a set of statements returns one result, based on some condition.

then statement has a query(`select * from tb_dana_user`) which returns multiple rows.

In your case either you can limit the value returned for `select * from tb_dana_user` to one at the same time column also one.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_dana_user WHERE userid=1234 AND password=1234) = 0)
            THEN (SELECT id FROM tb_dana_user limit 1) 
            ELSE (SELECT 'bar') 
    END
```